Near-future dystopia with young rebels, rich old people and "time-bombs"
Read this novel around 2010-2015 (200-250 pages IIRC.)
The story follows a group of mostly young, poor, urban kids that are struggling against the established order run by mostly older, very rich people who may or may not have some kind of youth serum available, not sure if I remember that bit.  It took place in North America, I think (not that this is very distinctive in SF).
What I do remember is that the rebels had these "time bombs" that they would use, almost like IEDs that would project a field of accelerated time and aging.
If I remember correctly, one of the "nasty plutocrats" had had her arm caught in one of those bombs' field that had consequently aged into a near-mummy state.

Was it was a novel / a short story / a comic / ...?

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

@Valorum I don't really see anything else I can add here from that checklist.  There's a (contentious) reason it left an impression in my mind, but that's just a feeling I had from the book and adding it to my description wouldn't be all that helpful.  However, the notion of someone getting partially caught in an bubble of accelerated aging is pretty unusual and should ring bells to some past readers.
